# Подключение к oracle через jdbc, не проходит авторизация

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Установлена Oracle Express 11g, когда открываю подключение, выдает

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017:
> invalid username/password; logon
> denied

Регистр проверял, в SQLPlus и PLSQL developer подключается нормально, пробовал несколько пользователей, в том числе sys.

Код:

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    private Connection connection;
    public boolean isConnected;

public DBConnection(String user, String pass) {
    try{
        isConnected = false;
        Properties cInfo = new Properties();
        cInfo.put("usr",user);
        cInfo.put("password",pass);
        this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, cInfo);
        isConnected = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в:

```
cInfo.put("usr",user);
cInfo.put("password",pass);
```

Заработало через

```
this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,pass);
```